# How do i share a folder with another Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: file-sharing

First there were 2 Computers, 1 with Win7 and 1 with Ubuntu 14.04.

I shared the Windows Folders, copied the files and then i erased the drive and installed Ubuntu on the "old Windows-"Computer. Now i want to send the files back but can't find a way to make both see each others shared folders in the network.

I installed Samba and shared folders on both computers. When i go to "Network" there is just the old windows Homegroup (without even a windows pc in the network). I don't even have access to the homegroup with either of the PCs since it asks for a login i don't know (and didn't setup as far as i know).

Can anyone help me please?
I am very frustrated right now :/
Thought this Linux-Thing would be easier... Runnung throuh tons of troubles since 5h+ :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to transfer files between 2 computers is NitroShare as it doesn't need any infrastructure and is easy to install and blindingly fast.  It also runs on everything: [Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/nitroshare), [Windows](http://windows.quickmediasolutions.com/nathan), ...

To install NitroShare on Ubuntu, use the following steps:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:george-edison55/nitroshare-dev
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nitroshare
```

A small icon now shows up in the menu bar:

[image: Nitroshare Menu bar Icon]

(do these steps on both computers)

3. On one computer, click the nitroshare icon and click "Send Directory" and send Documents, Pictures, ... over one by one.

**Warning!** Do not send the entire `/home` directory as that will copy your configuration files as well!

**Caution:** If you need to truly share files between multiple *Ubuntu only* computers, NFS is the way to go and when Windows comes into the play, samba is the way to go.

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**